# Кириллица в адресной строке

Tags: php

Я имею в виду чтобы в адресной строке отображалась кириллица а не какие-то непонятные символы.

Comment: возможно, это в большей степени зависит от браузера, нежели от сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кодируйте и декодируйте функциями:  `rawurlencode()`, `rawurldecode()`

```
<?

$uri = 'http://ru.yourdomain.com/questions/437199/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5';

echo '<a href="'.rawurldecode($uri).'">'.rawurldecode($uri).'</a>';   

?>
```

Почитать:
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurlencode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurldecode.php